# Convolution after applying a gaussian filter kernel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, mask, convolution

I have written a piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974801/my-functions-output-differs-from-conv2-output) to convolve an image with a given kernel. With the suggestion I received at the bottom of the page I managed to get [almost] exactly the same picture compared to when I use conv2 function. By almost I mean the images look the same when shown by `imshow`, but the values in the output pictures differ a little but. However, it becomes worse when I convolve a gaussian kernel with the image. Then the outputs of my own and conv2 function differ a lot! Why is that? Could you please tell me what is wrong with me code?

**Turns out I had done a mistake. I had done some modifications to the imageFilter() without noticing they exist for two days until now!**

You can see the imageFilter() code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974801/my-functions-output-differs-from-conv2-output).

```
gaussKernel = fspecial('gaussian', 3, 2);
testImage1 = imageFilter(image, gaussKernel);
testImage2 = conv2(image, gaussKernel);
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `imageFilter`?

Comment: Also, "differ a lot" is not a useful description.  Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: When you say the outer picture, do you mean the pixels towards the outer edge, such as those where the support of the function overlaps the edge? Also, irrelevant to your question, but your support appears quite small for a sigma of 2.

Comment: Do the images still differ if you crop the top and bottom three rows and the left and right three columns?

Comment: Turns out I had done a mistake. I had done some modifications to the imageFilter() without noticing they exist for two days until now!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons:

1. **Precision:**
   In the last line of your `imageFilter` method you are converting to the `uint8` data type (which is an 8-bit integer) and so you are basically sort of rounding your result:

   `finalImg = uint8(finalImg);`

   The native method `conv2` however is presented with a matrix `gaussKernel` of data type `double`, this does convolution in doubles and so in grater precision.
2. **Boundary conditions**: `conv2` has a third parameter (see [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)) that has to do with what the shape of the result. In your method you're calculating the result of the convolution with zero padding of the **same** size as the original image while `conv2` by default calculates the full convolution.

So a simple modification will yield identical results:

```
gaussKernel = fspecial('gaussian', 3, 2);
testImage1 = imageFilter(im, gaussKernel);
testImage2 = uint8(conv2(im, gaussKernel, 'same'));
```